# How to read bytes like 0x0, 0x1 etc. with the serial port in a C# program?

Tags: c#, serial-port, byte

I am building a C# application that reads data from the serial port. The data I sent is like a byte. 0x0, 0x1, 0x5, 0x100. It is like sending integers. I want to read the data, and print it in my debug console. The only problem is how.

After some research, I found out that I was able to print it like: 01, 6A, 52. But this isn't what I want. I only want the digits after the x. 0x0 has to be 0, 0x50 has to be 50, 0x145 has to be 145, etc.

The code I have now is:

```
private void serialPort_DataReceived(object sender, System.IO.Ports.SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
    readingbuffer = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(serialPort.ReadExisting());
    Debug.WriteLine(BitConverter.ToString(readingbuffer));
    this.Invoke(new EventHandler(procesReading));
}
```

Every time the serial port received some data, the code above is triggered.

I don't know if it is possible to read the digits after the x, so, could anybody assist me a little bit?

Comment: If you want just a numeric value, then why you convert it back to string? You already have it in "readingbuffer" as array of bytes.

Comment: It looks like you are able to *read* bytes, so what is your question?

Comment: try `Debug.Print(data)` .

Comment: I am sending something like 0x20, that has to be printed like 20. But it is printing like 14. Also, when I print it directly, I get some chars like C, $, &, j, B instead of a number.

Comment: Tried to read this bytes in `byte[]` ?

Comment: @PGriep: apparently you are in need of reading >>[this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII)<<

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
byte[] buf = new byte[4]; // creates a byte array the size of the data you want to recieve
int bufCount = 0;
private void serialPort1_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
  bufCount += serialPort.Read(buf, bufCount, buf.Length - bufCount);
  if(bufCount == buf.Length) 
      serialPort.Close();
}
```

EDIT:

You can then convert it to Hex string like that

```
string hex = BitConverter.ToString(buf).Replace("-", string.Empty);
```